# Unable to establish relationship between two objects in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I'm writing an RSpec called Leads controller spec. In that I'm writing a test for create action of lead controller. Now my lead controller calls Project model to create an object(Project) which also creates Contact object and assigns it to project. but when I try to test whether my Project model creating a Contact object or no, The tests are getting failed. I don't know why my contact object is not getting created:(

My leads_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST #create" do
    it "should create a contact too" do
      my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))
      expect{
      post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
      }.to change(Contact, :count).by(1)
    end
    it "should be equal to last created contact" do
      my_lead = Fabricate(:project, id:  Faker::Number.number(10))
      post :create, project: my_lead.attributes
      expect(Project.last.contact).to eq(Contact.last)
    end
  end
```

leads_controller.rb

```
 def create
    if @lead = Project.add_new_lead(lead_params)
      @lead.create_activity :create_new_lead, owner: current_user
      puts "My lead in create action: #{@lead.inspect}"
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back, :alert => "Email is already Taken"}
      end
    end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to leads_path }
      end 
  end
```

Project.rb

```
def add_new_lead(inputs, data = {})
      if !Contact.where(email: inputs[:email]).present?
        contact = Contact.create(phone: inputs[:phone], email: inputs[:email], fullname: inputs[:fullname])
        project = Project.create(name: inputs[:fullname], flat_status: inputs[:flat_status], flat_type: inputs[:flat_type], flat_area: inputs[:area], location: inputs[:locality], address: inputs[:site_address], customer_type: inputs[:customer_type])
        project.contact = contact
        project.save

        project

      else
        return nil
      end
    end
```

contact_fabricator.rb

```
require 'faker'
Fabricator(:contact) do
email { "email_#{Kernel.rand(1..30000)}@prestotest.com" }
fullname "project#{Kernel.rand(1..30000)}"
address "address#{Kernel.rand(1..30000)}"

end
```

project_fabricator.rb

```
require 'faker'
Fabricator(:project) do

    contact
end
```

contact.rb

```
  field :phone,             type: String           
  field :email,             type: String
  field :fullname,          type: String
  field :status,            type: String,       default: "DEFAULT"
  field :address,               type: String
  field :new_address,       type: String
  field :other_data,        type: Hash,         default: {} 

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "Email already taken"
```

Comment: Fail message: expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Comment: Is it possible that your test didn't create a new `Contact` because a matching contact was already existing in the database or because a validation failed? Do you delete your database between two runs of your test suite? Do you have validations on your `Contact` model?

Comment: Yes spickermann I do have validations to Contact model as you can see the last two lines of Contact.rb file. But If I remove the validations then the tests will go green but I need validations anyway.

Comment: I cleaned my db between two runs of test suite

Answer (score 0):

You are using the factories wrong in your spec. You want to use [`Fabricate.attributes_for(:project)`](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#fabricating-objects) instead of creating a record and taking its attributes as that will cause any uniqueness validations to fail.

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe ProjectsContoller

  describe "POST #create" do

    # don't forget to test with invalid input!
    context "with invalid attributes" do
      let(:attributes) { { foo: 'bar' } }
      it "does not create a project" do
        expect do
          post :create, attributes
        end.to_not change(Project, :count)
      end
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      let(:attributes) { Fabricate.attributes_for(:project) }
      it "creates a project" do
        expect do
          post :create, attributes
        end.to change(Project, :count).by(+1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When it comes to the rest of your controller you should very likely be using [nested attributes](https://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/nested_attributes.html) instead as you are not handling the case where the validation of contact fails. You're also using `Contact.create` when you should be using `Contact.new`.

Note that this is a pretty advanced topic and you might want to learn the basics first and revisit it later.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
  validates_associated :contact
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

---

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      format.html { render :new } # don't redirect!
    else
      format.html { redirect_to leads_path }
    end
  end

  private

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:foo, :bar, contact_attributes: [:email, :name, :stuff, :more_stuff])
    end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :foo %>

  # These are the attributes for the contact
  <%= fields_for :contact do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.text_field :email %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```